# iOS - Asynchronous Image Downloading

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, image, asynchronous

I am writing an app which is going to be displaying images found on my server in a UIImageView.

I need something that will asynchronously download the image and cache it while putting it in the UIImageView.
The download also needs to be able to be cancelled when I press a button.

Can anyone point me in the direction of something that can do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the old times the framework for that was ASIHTTPRequest but is an abandoned project now. This https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking seems to be popular now.

Comment: +1 for [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) which has a robust asynchronous API for UIImage handling over the network.

Comment: Even though I haven't got it working yet, the documentation seems to indicate it does exactly what I want plus so much more. I'll even be using it for something I have already built. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the performSelectorInBackground:withObject: - method from NSObject ;)

Advise: The updating of the view must run on the main thread!

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: performSelectorInBackground:withObject: is a great way of doing it if you don't want to use an external library and are only downloading a single image without wanting to block the interface.