# Really bad performance with scrolling in UITableView with subviews

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, subview

I'm just not getting what is going on here.

I have a UITableView where each cell contain some subviews and it works fine and all. Unfortunately, the performance is horrendous, scrolling is just way too choppy. I read that maybe you can subclass UITableViewCell and that could help performance, but I'm not sure on how to that or implement another solution that would fix the issue. 
I've posted the delegate method for the tableView below, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UIImageView* imageView;
UILabel* ttitle;
UILabel* ttitle2;
UILabel* ttitle3;
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    // Configure cell:
    // *** This section should configure the cell to a state independent of
    //  whatever row or section the cell is in, since it is only executed
    //  once when the cell is first created.


    imageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 11.0, 50.0, 50.0)];
    [imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius=5.0;
    imageView.tag=1;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];

    ttitle = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70.0, 7.0, 200, 20)] autorelease];
    ttitle.textColor= [UIColor blackColor];
    ttitle.numberOfLines=1;
    ttitle.tag=69;
    ttitle.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    ttitle.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Bold" size:15.0];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:ttitle];

    if (indexPath.row==0) {

        CGSize size=[[[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"content"] sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(265.0f, CGFLOAT_MAX) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        ttitle2 = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70.0, 27.5, 200, size.height)] autorelease];
        ttitle2.textColor= [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        ttitle2.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        ttitle2.numberOfLines=0;
        ttitle2.tag=70;
        ttitle2.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        ttitle2.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        ttitle2.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14.0];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:ttitle2];

        ttitle3 = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70.0, ttitle2.frame.origin.y+ttitle2.frame.size.height-8.0, 210, 40)] autorelease];
        ttitle3.textColor= [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        ttitle3.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        ttitle3.numberOfLines=1;
        ttitle3.tag=71;
        ttitle3.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        ttitle3.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        ttitle3.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:11.0];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:ttitle3];


    }
    else{

        CGSize size=[[[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"content"] sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(265.0f, CGFLOAT_MAX) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        ttitle2 = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70.0, 27.0, 200, size.height)] autorelease];
        ttitle2.textColor= [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        ttitle2.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        ttitle2.numberOfLines=0;
        ttitle2.tag=70;
        ttitle2.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        ttitle2.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        ttitle2.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14.0];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:ttitle2];


        ttitle3 = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70.0, ttitle2.frame.origin.y+ttitle2.frame.size.height-9.0, 210, 40)] autorelease];
        ttitle3.textColor= [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        ttitle3.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        ttitle3.numberOfLines=1;
        ttitle3.tag=71;
        ttitle3.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        ttitle3.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        ttitle3.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:11.0];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:ttitle3];

    }


}
else {
    imageView = (UIImageView *) [cell viewWithTag:1];
    ttitle=( UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:69];
    ttitle2=( UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:70];
    ttitle3=( UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:71];
}

//STUFFOUTSIDE

// Customize cell:
// *** This section should customize the cell depending on what row or section
//  is passed in indexPath, since this is executed every time this delegate method
//  is called.



imageView.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"thumbnail"]]]];

[ttitle setText:[[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name"]];
[ttitle2 setText:[[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"content"]];

NSString* first=[[[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"hashtag"] stringByAppendingString:@"     "];
NSString* second =[first stringByAppendingString:[[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"place"]];
NSString* third=[second stringByAppendingString:@"        "];
NSString* fourth=[third stringByAppendingString:@"¤ "];
NSString* conversion=[[[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"counter"] stringValue];
NSString* fifth=[fourth stringByAppendingString:conversion];
[ttitle3 setText:fifth];

return cell;
```

}

Comment: Not a major cause of your lag, but you're leaking your UIImageView when you create it up near the top.

Comment: There are autorelease calls, so you know it's not ARC.

Comment: I've never understood why it is harder to create an inherited class of the `UITableViewCell` instead of adding the many regular subviews and adjusting their properties one-by-one programmatically... loading the view form a nib can be pretty fast and the maintenance of it is very easy in the _IB_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're synchronously fetching data from an URL for getting the image for each cell. This means that for each cell you're blocking the main thread until the data has been fetched from the internet.

You'll have to do the image loading asynchronously on a background thread and update the cells when the image is loaded. There are plenty of blog posts about this.

**Update:**
There's no way to tell whether the image URL is local or not, but I assume that it's a remote URL and the images are not stored inside your app.

Comment: +1 Inafriger also has some good points, but this is almost certainly the majority of the lag. Even if the URL is local and you're fetching from disk, this is going to be far too slow for configuring a table view cell.

Comment: You're right they're remote. So I'm looking to populating the tableView with an ansyc dispatch and simply have all of the subview assignments happen inside of there. Would this be the right way to go?

Comment: @RobNapier: FYI, I have an app with very good scrolling performance if the files are local and loaded synchronously, as long as they don't have to be scaled when being assigned to the image view.  I was actually surprised by how well it worked, lol.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of issues that can cause lag but I see three probable causes in this case:

1. The background color of cell subviews (your labels, etc) shouldn't be clear unless absolutely required. This kills scrolling performace.
2. If the image being set in the imageView is not the right size and has to be scaled, this will cause major lag. If this is the case, you will either need to save an appropriately sized image to display in the table, or load them asynchronously so that the table will scroll without waiting for the image to load.
3. As Fabian mentions in the comment below, since you are downloading these images from the web, you **definitely** want to load the images asynchronously.  Every time that a cell is displayed, it has to wait for the image to download before moving onto displaying the next one.  This **is** the biggest problem that you have with this code right now.  The following question has a few different options for doing this:  [iOS - Asynchronous Image Downloading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9789009/937822)

Comment: No matter what size the images are, loading them synchronously from the web will always be very, very slow. ;)

Comment: @FabianKreiser: True, IF they are coming from the web!

Comment: @FabianKreiser: And, if I had read that part of the code, I would have seen that he is, lol.  Thanks!