# Lazy loading getting crash with Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:for

Tags: ios, uitableview, lazy-loading

I'm loading `UITableView` cell images according to the lazy loading. here is my code for cell for row at indexpath

```
else if (tableView.tag==4)//All Songs
{

    cell4=(SongCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SongCell"];



   if (cell4 == nil) {

       NSArray *nib =[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"SongCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell4=[nib objectAtIndex:0];

   }




    [cell4 setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

    cell4.lblSong.text=[[arrSongList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"SONGTITLE"];
    cell4.lblArtist.text=[[arrSongList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"ARTISTNAME"];


    if ([dicSongimages valueForKey:[[arrSongList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"SONGIMG"]]) {
        cell4.imgSong.image=[dicSongimages valueForKey:[[arrSongList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"SONGIMG"]];

        [cell4.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
        cell4.activityIndicator.hidden=YES;

    }





        else
        {
            if (!isDragging_msg && !isDecliring_msg)
            {
                [dicSongimages setObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"] forKey:[[arrSongList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"SONGIMG"]];
                cell4.activityIndicator.hidden=NO;
                [cell4.activityIndicator startAnimating];

                [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(downloadImage:) withObject:indexPath];
            }
            else
            {
                cell4.imgSong.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"];
                cell4.activityIndicator.hidden=YES;
                [cell4.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
            }

        }





    [cell4.btnTick addTarget:self action:@selector(tickButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside] ;

    [cell4.btnAddtoMyList addTarget:self action:@selector(topLeft:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    return cell4;
}
```

this method for download images from those URLs.

-(void)downloadImage:(NSIndexPath *)path{

```
if(path.row<[arrSongList count])
{

NSString *str=[[arrSongList objectAtIndex:path.row]valueForKey:@"SONGIMG"];

UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]]];




[dicSongimages setObject:img forKey:str];

[tblSongs performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:@"TAG_4" waitUntilDone:NO];
```

}

My problem is

`[dicSongimages setObject:img forKey:str];` is getting crash it says

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert nil value`

but image is displaying properly when I go to that link through the browser. All those images are `.jpg` format. what is the problem with this. plz help me.

Thanks

Comment: once check placeholder.png image is there or not?

Comment: it crashing only when the path is [0,47]

Answer (score 1):

the problem is your synchronous loading of the images. As your code tries to set the 'img' object into dictionary before the image has been downloaded. This makes a nil object to be set in to a dictionary which is not permissible. So the idea is to work on different threads. You can use asynchronous calls to download the image.There are some frameworks out there that you can use. e.g AFNetworking, ASIHTTPRequest(though abandoned). 
You can also run your code for downloading on different threads via perfromSelector method.

Answer (score 0):

You are used synchronous image download which is not good idea

You need to use asynchronous image download

check this

[iOS - Asynchronous Image Downloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789009/ios-asynchronous-image-downloading)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a perfect library [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

It not only downloads asynchronously but also handle such fatal errors, to prevent application crash. Also provide placeholder image, if no image found at specified URL.
Very easy to implement.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Here we use the new provided setImageWithURL: method to load the web image
    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

    cell.textLabel.text = @"My Text";
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: You can use this in populating tableview rows, and even anywhere where you want to show image from a URL. It also caches images, so if request is sent to same URL again, it will show image from cache without downloading again, which fastens application UI.

Comment: Even Facebook uses it according to Library author https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/wiki/Who-Use-SDWebImage